# mod_rewrite with URL in the query string

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I'm having some difficulty with `mod_rewrite` when a `URL` is part of the query string.

My current rewrite rule is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?action=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This will rewrite `http://example.com/Controller/action&url=example.com` to `http://example.com/index.php?action=Controller/action&url=example.com`, which works as expected, with `$_GET` being:

```
Array
(
    [action] => Controller/action
    [url] => example.com
)
```

However, I wish for `$_GET['url']` to include `http://` and a query string of its own, e.g. `http://example.com/?a=1&b=2`, so that `$_GET` will be:

```
Array
(
    [action] => Controller/action
    [url] => http://example.com/?a=1&b=2
)
```

I first tried encoding the (query string) `URL` with [`rawurlencode`](https://www.php.net/rawurlencode):

```
http://example.com/Controller/action&url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%3Fa%3D1%26b%3D2
```

This, however, gives the `Apache` error:

> **Not Found**
>
> The requested URL /Controller/action&url=http://example.com/?a=1&b=2 was not found on
> this server.

My first assumption is that the encoded `/`s are breaking the rewrite rule, and so I removed them, fixing the error. This, however, causes two problems. The main being that there are no longer any `/`s in the query string (so that the `URL` is `http:example.com?a=1&b=2`), and the second is that the `&`s are being treated literally, giving a `$_GET` value of:

```
Array
(
    [action] => Controller/action
    [url] => http:example.com?a=1
    [b] => 2
)
```

If anyone knows how to get around these issues I'd be very appreciative.

**Clarification**

It should be worth pointing out that this needs to work regardless of what specific query string is used, e.g. `$_GET` could be:

```
Array
(
    [action] => A/b/c/d
    [href] => https://test.com/Test/test?test=test
    [rhyme] => Jack & Jill
)
```

The only constant is that it starts with a `/` separated list of words (e.g. `/Controller/action/param1/param2/param3...`). The optional query string could be anything, e.g. `&user_id=1&api_key=1234&optional_option_1=a&optional_option_2=b&url=...`.

So imagine third-party access where they access our site via a URL (e.g. http://example.com/Dashboard/view with custom parameters of their choice (so if they use `&name=Michael&age=25&uihfwiu=alrjnwvur` it will display:

> **name**: Michael
>
> **age**: 25
>
> **uihfwiu**: alrjnwvur

Currently, the only problems are when the values contain `/`s or `&`s -- it works fine as-is when they're not present.

Comment: The simplest would be to use what worked before and prepend `http://` simply with PHP `$url = 'http://' . $_GET['url'];` I would not put too much into rewrite, especially not URL in URL,.. URL inception. `http://example.com/Controller/action&url=example.com` as no `?` before the first parameter anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, problem solved. Rather than `&url=` I needed `?url=`, and the `mod_rewrite` needed the `QSA` flag:

> http://example.com/Controller/action?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%3Fa%3D1%26b%3D2

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

After long discussion it turned out that OP was using an incorrectly encoded URL. Correctly encoded URL should be:

```
/Controller/action&url=http%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%252F%253Fa%253D1%2526b%253D2&name=Michael&age=25
```

Comment: It really needs to be dynamic; it won't always be `&url` -- it could be anything (or nothing).

Comment: Sorry, when I meant that it's dynamic I meant that I can't specify `&url=http://$2/?a=1&b=2` as part of the rewrite rule as I don't have control over what URL (or any other parameter) is being sent. It's for third-party access. The query string could be anything. The only constant is that it starts with a `/` separated list of words (e.g. `/Controller/action/param1/param2/param3...` followed by the custom query string, e.g. `&user_id=1&api_key=1234&url=...`.

Comment: ok and `&url=http://$2/?a=1&b=2` must only be done for `&url=something` right leaving other query parameters intact?

Comment: The `url` might not have `?a=1&b=2` -- it could have anything. And rather than `url` the key might be `a`, or `b`, or `c`, or anything.

Comment: But then it is not clear to me under what conditions should we make `http://example.com/?a=1&b=2` in the query string by rule?

Comment: Imagine third-party access where they access our site via a URL (e.g. `http://example.com/Dashboard/view` with custom parameters of their choice (so if they use `&name=Michael&age=25` it will display `Name: Michael, Age: 25`). It's entirely dynamic

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44877/discussion-between-anubhava-and-michaelrushton)

Comment: I totally understand the dynamic part but I think you didn't understand my question. My question was under what conditions you want to make example.com/?a=1&b=2 in the query string?

Comment: When the user accesses via `http://example.com/Dashboard/view&url={http://example.com/?a=1&b=2}` -- the `{}` just my clarification to you that all of it is part of `&url`, otherwise the `&b=2` could be seen as a separate parameter. The bit inside `{}` (which wouldn't be present in the actual `URL`) could be anything.

Comment: But a URL can be: `/Dashboard/view&url=http://example.com/?a=1&b=2&name=Michael&age=25` now how to figure out whether `name=Michael` is part of url parameter OR actual URL? This is because of bad URL encoding actually where your clients are not sending properly encoded URL.

Comment: Yes; that's the issue I'm trying to resolve. I tried encoding the `url` parameter so that I was sending `/Dashboard/view&url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%3Fa%3D1%26b%3D2&name=Michael&age=25`, but that lead to the (Apache) Not Found error.

Comment: Actually that one is bad encoding. Correct one is this `/Controller/action&url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%3Fa%3D18b%3D2&age=25`

Comment: That gives: the Apache Not Found error `The requested URL /Controller/action&url=http://example.com/?a=18b=2&age=25 was not found on this server.`

Comment: No I have just tried that with `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?action=$1 [L,NE,QSA]` and got `index.php` opened with correct query string.

Comment: Maybe stackoverflow isn't displaying the string as you entered it because it's definitely not working for me?

Comment: And it is definitely working for me. SO displays correct text if enclosed in code syntax. Do you have some other rules OR any other .htaccess in yor path?

Comment: Yes; it's the `.htaccess` from the `HTML5 Boilerplate` (4.3.0) -- the only addition being that I gave in my question.

Comment: I'm getting the 404 error with your encoded string. Also, isn't `a%3D18b%3D2` the encoded version of `a=18b=2` rather than `a=1&b=2`?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, this encoded URL worked for me: `/Controller/action&url=http%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%252F%253Fa%253D1%2526b%253D2&age=25`